# Is there any good ways to improve the parser's performance generated using antlr4?

Tags: java, antlr4, sqlperformance

I have tried a few days to fix my grammar file(uniformSQL.g4) in order to improve the parser performance but still failed. The parser cost 4000+ ms to parser through the SQL case. And I also tried to use SLL(*) strategy, it is fast but come out a lot of mismatch cases.

So I wonder how to get the best performance when designing the grammar.

I also tried to lower the parse tree'height when designing grammar, but the speed turned out to be slower.

Looking forward to your suggestion,thanks.

This is my uniformSQL.g4 grammar file:
https://github.com/ihainan/GBase-8a-MPP-Cluster-SQL-Parser/blob/master/src/main/java/cn/edu/bit/linc/sqlparser/antlr/uniformSQL.g4

And this is my SQL test case(280+ lines):
https://github.com/ihainan/GBase-8a-MPP-Cluster-SQL-Parser/blob/master/test.sql

Comment: Don't write your lexer keyword rules like that. Just define the keywords as strings. Surely ANTLR has a case-insensitive scanner mode?

Comment: No singular answer to a question like this.  There are many improvements that could be made, but no certainty they would have any impact.  Best approach is to quantify lexing vs parsing times and then rule times to narrow down where the most time is being consumed.  Post the results and much more focused help can be provided.

Comment: @EJP - Not native, but the lexer accepts an InputStream. Easy enough to apply a keyword specific, lower-casing filter to the input character reader. This only works, however, if the keywords are context-free.